# How to catch specific exceptions when sending mail?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have the following piece of code

```
try
{
  if (!bDebug)
    smtp.Send(m);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  wl("Meldingen kunne ikke sendes til en eller flere mottakere.", ConsoleColor.Red);
  wl(e.Message, ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
  using (var errorfile = System.IO.File.CreateText("error-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".txt"))
  {
    errorfile.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    if (e.GetType() == typeof(SmtpFailedRecipientException))
    {
      var se = (SmtpFailedRecipientException) e;
      errorfile.WriteLine(se.FailedRecipient);
    }
    errorfile.WriteLine(e.ToString());
  }
}
```

Where `wl` is a shortcut for writing to the console with color, and the text in the first line says "The message could not be sent to one or more recipients.

Previously I only caught the `SmtpFailedRecipientException`, but when it started failing in some other steps I shoved the generic `Exception` in there. So the part I'm wondering about is where I'm casting the Exception object into a more specific object to get the `FailedRecipient` property. Could/should this be done in another more proper way? It seems a bit clunky...

Comment: I ended up switching off sending mail natively and started using Mandrill instead ;)
``wl`` was just a console-logging wrapper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have multiple catch branches:

```
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException se)
{
  using (var errorfile = System.IO.File.CreateText("error-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".txt"))
  {
    errorfile.WriteLine(se.StackTrace);  
    // variable se is already the right type, so no need to cast it      
    errorfile.WriteLine(se.FailedRecipient);       
    errorfile.WriteLine(se.ToString());
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  wl("Meldingen kunne ikke sendes til en eller flere mottakere.", ConsoleColor.Red);
  wl(e.Message, ConsoleColor.DarkRed);   

  // for other error types just write the info without the FailedRecipient
  using (var errorfile = System.IO.File.CreateText("error-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".txt"))
  {
    errorfile.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);        
    errorfile.WriteLine(e.ToString());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try somthing like this([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20110314032352/http://aspdotnetcode.source-of-humor.com/Articles/Emails/CatchingSendingEmailExceptionsErrorHandling.aspx)):

> We're going to learn how to catch/handle different types of
>   exceptions/errors that might occur while sending an email using
>   ASP.Net. We'll implement error/exception handling using different
>   exception classes available in `System.Net.Mail`.
>
> First to learn how to send an email using ASP.Net visit [this
>   link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100829145731/http://aspdotnetcode.source-of-humor.com/Articles/Emails/HowToSendEmailFromAspxPageUsingGmailAccount.aspx). Notice that in the above article (lead by link) the
>   'SendEmails' catches only a generic exception and in case ASP.Net
>   encounters an error while sending email it would be like 'Sending
>   email failed etc'. We'll extend the error handling functionality for
>   the above article. So lets get started by openning the solution we
>   created previously. We already have put a try-catch block that catches
>   a generic exception that tells very little about what might have gone
>   wrong. Let's catch different types of exception right away:
>
> Catch the `SmtpException`: The `SmtpException` class has a property
>   '`StatusCode`' which is actually an enumeration that gets the
>   error/exception code value returned by the SMTP server when an email
>   message is transmitted. It also provides more details of
>   error/exception that can occur during the email sending process. e.g.
>
> ```
> catch (SmtpException smtpException) 
> { // You can put a switch block to check for different exceptions or errors    
>
>  // To checks if the destination mailbox is busy 
>  if (smtpException.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy) 
>    throw smtpException; 
>
>  // To check if the client is authenticated or is allowed to send email using the specified SMTP host 
>  if (smtpException.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.ClientNotPermitted) 
>    throw smtpException; 
>  // The following code checks if the email message is too large to be stored in destination mailbox 
>
>  if (smtpException.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.ExceededStorageAllocation) 
>    throw smtpException; 
>  // To check if the email was successfully sent to the SMTP service 
>
>  if (smtpException.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.Ok) 
>    throw smtpException; 
>  // When the SMTP host is not found check for the following value 
>
>  if (smtpException.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.GeneralFailure) 
>    throw smtpException;             
> }
> ```
>
> Catch the `SmtpFailedRecipientException`: The
>   `SmtpFailedRecipientException` class deals with the exception related to
>   the recipient of the email e.g. SMTP is not able to send the email to
>   a recipient. The `SmtpFailedRecipientException` occurs when `SmtpClient`
>   is not able to complete a `SmtpClient.Send()` or `SmtpClient.SendAsync()`
>   operation to a particular recipient. To catch this exception use the
>   following code:
>
> ```
> catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException smtpFailedRecipientException) 
> { 
>  // Get the email that is causing email sending failed exception 
>  String emailCausingException = smtpFailedRecipientException.FailedRecipient; 
>
>  // Get the status code why and what is actually causing an email sending error 
>  System.Net.Mail.SmtpStatusCode statusCode = smtpFailedRecipientException.StatusCode; 
>
>  // Take some action either re-send the email again or do some error handling code here 
> }
> ```
>
> Catch the `SmtpFailedRecipientsException`: The
>   `SmtpFailedRecipientsException` is actually a collection of
>   `SmtpFailedRecipientException` objects serving the same purpose. It is
>   used to handle exceptions when `SmtpClient` is not able to send emails
>   to one or more recipients.
>
> ```
> catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException smtpFailedRecipientsException) 
> { 
>  ArrayList emailCausingException = new ArrayList(); 
>
>  foreach (SmtpFailedRecipientException smtpFailedRecipientException 
>                in smtpFailedRecipientsException.InnerExceptions) 
> { 
>    // Get the email that is causing email sending failed exception 
>    // Add it to a list of emails with exceptions 
>    emailCausingException.Add(smtpFailedRecipientException.FailedRecipient);
>
>    // Get the status code why and what is actually causing an email sending error 
>    System.Net.Mail.SmtpStatusCode statusCode = smtpFailedRecipientException.StatusCode; 
>    // Take some action either re-send the email again or do some error handling 
>    // You can also log or print this status code for an individual recipient here 
>    if (statusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy) 
>    { 
>      //Re-Send email after some time 
>      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 
>      //smtpClient.Send(); 
>      //Email sending code here 
>    } 
>  } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Link https://web.archive.org/web/20100829145731/http://aspdotnetcode.source-of-humor.com/Articles/Emails/HowToSendEmailFromAspxPageUsingGmailAccount.aspx not found **Page cannot be crawled or displayed due to robots.txt.**